Memory Mapped Configuration Space for PCIe Device - failed to rescan
PCIe devices fail to reassign BAR addresses when Ubuntu 22.04.4 is booted. But if pci=nommconf is added kernel boot command-line in grub, then it is ok. But I think it just hides some potential problems. My guess is the memory mapped configuration address may be invalid which triggers a rescan by kernel for re-assignment of BARs. Is there a reference document that describes the requirements of memory mapped configuration base addresses?
Thank you,
tigerdxy
